# Using one progressDialog in two or more android stringRequest Volley

Tags: android-volley, progressdialog

In my code I have to `stringRequest` Volley that works just fine, but now I want to use a `progressDialog`. I have create 1 method to put the `progressDialog` like this

```java
private void showProgress(String message) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading Data " + message);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

and I have these 2 `stringRequest` like this:

```java
private void fetchDataPoMurni(final String tipe, final String user_id, final String last_date) {
    showProgress("Murni");
    String tag_string_req = "Request Po Dapat";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
        AppConfig.URL_FETCH_REPORT_PO,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");

                    if(!error) {
                        JSONArray resultPo =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        for(int i = 0; i < resultPo.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject result = (JSONObject) resultPo.get(i);
                            String _cabang_id = result.getString("branch_id");
                            String _area_id = result.getString("areacode");
                            String _cabang = result.getString("branch_name");
                            Log.d("FETCHING DATA MURNI: ", _cabang_id + " " + _area_id + " " + _cabang);
                            dataBaseHelper.insertDataPoMurni(new PoModel(_cabang_id.trim(), _area_id.trim(), _cabang.trim()));
                        }
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jsonObject.getString("result");
                        showAlertDialog(errorMsg);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    showAlertDialog(e.getMessage());
                }

                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                showAlertDialog(volleyError.getMessage());
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tipe", tipe);
                params.put("uid", user_id);
                params.put("last_date", last_date);
                return params;
            }
        };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
}
```

and the other request:

```java
private void fetchDataPoDapat(final String tipe, final String user_id, final String last_date) {
    showProgress("Dapat");
    String tag_string_req = "Request Po Dapat";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
        AppConfig.URL_FETCH_REPORT_PO,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");

                    if(!error) {
                        JSONArray resultPo =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        for(int i = 0; i < resultPo.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject result = (JSONObject) resultPo.get(i);
                            String _cabang_id = result.getString("branch_id");
                            String _area_id = result.getString("areacode");
                            String _cabang = result.getString("branch_name");
                            Log.d("FETCHING DATA DAPAT : ", _cabang_id + " " + _area_id + " " + _cabang);
                            dataBaseHelper.insertDataPoDapat(new PoModel(_cabang_id.trim(), _area_id.trim(), _cabang.trim()));
                        }
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jsonObject.getString("result");
                        showAlertDialog(errorMsg);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    showAlertDialog(e.getMessage());
                }
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                showAlertDialog(volleyError.getMessage());
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tipe", tipe);
                params.put("uid", user_id);
                params.put("last_date", last_date);
                return params;
            }
        };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
}
```

I execute the 2 request through a method like this:

```java
private void exeRequest() {
    fetchDataPoMurni(valuea,value2,value3);
    fetchDataPoDapat(valueb,value2,value3);
}
```

the `progressDialog` is showing, and the message is changing, but the problem is when reach the second request the `progressDialog` doesn't want to dismiss.

Whats wrong with my code above, and how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you solve it and do you encounter `skipped frames` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showProgress(String message) {
  progressDialog=null;// Initialize to null 
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
      progressDialog.setTitle("Loading Data " + message);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
   progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
   progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
   progressDialog.show();
 }
```

Try this .. Initialize all instances of the progressDialog to null as soon as you create a new progress dialog

Comment: No luck, still same.